# Strange drag effect on 3rd HP monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have attached 3rd monitor on my machine, HP E231, and now the image on this monitor looks like there is a drag effect for each icon or text. The picture seems blurry.

[image]

Check the file icon and see like there is a shadow, like the icon is duplicated 2-3 times with a transparency.

This monitor is attached to VGA port, while other use DVI and HDMI ports.

How can I fix this? I am already using the latest stable NVidia drivers.

Comment: Take a look at your screenshot. There are no artifacts I can see. You may want to check the connection to the monitor or even try a different screen to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar issue, check the cable!!!

I had a new VGA cable so never thought it could be faulty because it worked on the previous monitor. But when I switched to a new VGA cable, the issue was gone.

So in my case, it was a faulty cable!